# VCO output is its maximum frequency

Tags: pcb-design, pll, vco

I am trying to design PLL for generating 122.8MHz from 40 MHz REFIN. I am following the [CN0290 EVM](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0290.pdf) reference for the design.

I have used [CVCO33CL-0110-0150](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/94/CVCO33CL_0110_0150-2303240.pdf) VCO in the place of VCXO in EVM.

When I am writing the registers of [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf) for different frequencies, the VCO is outputting its maximum output frequency 150MHz, irrespective of the registers being written into it.

In what cases the above behaviour of the VCO might take place?

Edit:-

I am measuring a tuning voltage of 4.995V. I am supplying the PLL with VP of  5V

Comment: Work back from the tuning voltage - what is it?

Comment: @Andyaka I am measuring a tuning voltage of 4.995V, I am supplying 5V to the VP pin of the PLL

Comment: So now you can say that the VCO is not the culprit. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Are you confident you have programmed the chip correctly?  Try to outputting the N and R counters from the Muxout and check they are correct. Is the PD polarity correct? Also, a 5V tuning voltage should give closer to 170MHz according to the datasheet you linked.

Comment: @Tesla23 Is the PD polarity correct? Do you mean Phase detector polarity or?

Comment: yes, the PD Polarity bit, DB7 of the Initialization Latch

Comment: @Tesla23 Yes, the PD bit is set to positive